# GeoServer access data file reside remotely

Tags: curl, server, geoserver, geotiff

I have geoserver installed in my web server and I want to create a GeoTIFF layer.
I am accessing geoserver through my local machine and I have GeoTIFF file reside in my local machine. The problem is geoserver doesn't recognize the path of the file I specified so it is unable to create the layer for me.

Below is my curl command,

exec('curl -u admin:geoserver -v -XPUT -H "Content-type:image/tiff" --data-binary "http://192.168.1.2:82/TrueMarble.32km.1350x675.tif" "http://107.167.186.125:8080/geoedge/rest/workspaces/geoedge/coveragestores/st_tif_layer_8/file.geotiff" 
 ');

It creates coverage but doesn't create layer there, Can't I access my file using IP address, should it reside in the same server as geoserver installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is possible but I think your curl syntax is wrong. I would use soemthing like:

```
curl -u admin:geoserver -v -XPUT -H "Content-type:image/tiff" --data-binary @TrueMarble.32km.1350x675.tif "http://107.167.186.125:8080/geoedge/rest/workspaces/geoedge/coveragestores/st_tif_layer_8/file.geotiff"
```

where the file is refered to by name (since it is local) otherwise curl will just send the file name as the data.

From the curl man page:

> If you start the data with the letter @, the rest  should  be  a
>                 file  name  to read the data from, or - if you want curl to read
>                 the data from stdin. Multiple files can also be specified. Post‐
>                 ing  data  from  a  file  named 'foobar' would thus be done with
>                 --data @foobar. When --data is told to read  from  a  file  like
>                 that, carriage returns and newlines will be stripped out.

Comment: Thank u so much, u saved a whole lot of my time.